# Determine the values of real parameters ....

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

```
If you have an idea, please, do not leave the page, just write it, I will be very thankful.
```

We have the function $$f:R\setminus \{-1 \}\to{R}$$

$$\color{maroon}{f(x)={x^2+ax+b\over x+1}}$$  $${a,b\in R}$$

For which values of parameters $a$ and $b$ the function admits an oblique asymptote $$\color{green}{y=x+1}$$
and the critical point$$x_0=1$$.

What I've done is this:
I used the fact that $$f'(x_0)=0$$. Hence, I've got  that $$\color{violet}{3+a-b=0}$$

The problem is I do not know how to use the condition of the oblique asymptote. I hope you will explain me , thank you very much!!!

Comment: Do you usually spell all functions in blood, or juts the particularly annoying ones ? :-)

Comment: @Lucian It's a hurtful exercise, unwilling to obey, so the function deserves it :). Do you have an idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{x^2+ax+b}{x+1}=x+a-1+\frac{b-a+1}{x+1}.
$$
Hence $a-1=1$, unless I made some mistake...

Comment: Sorry , but I do not quiet understand your explanation. How have you got that $a-1=1$. Have you used the condition of the oblique asymptote?

Comment: From the decomposition, you immediately deduce that $y=x+a-1$ is the equation of the asymptote, since the remainder tends to zero at infinity. Instructors don't teach this very often, but the equation of oblique asymptotes of rational functions is easily determined by performing the division and looking for the leading (if any) polynomial of first degree.

Comment: It's an interesting and really convincing solution, can you explain me how you did the decomposition? And also another question: does your method hold only for oblique asymptotes? Is this a universal approach to the problems of such genre?

Comment: I just divided the two polynomials: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division It is based on the fact that an oblique asymptote is defined by the condition $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)-(mx+q)=0$. Actually it works also in the case $m=0$ and $q \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. for horizontal asymptotes. Of course it works whenever you have a quotient of two polynomials: as a by-product, you understand that an oblique asymptote can exist only if the degree of the numerator exceeds the degree of the denominator by one.

Comment: Thank you very much, you just showed me the easy way. I've solved this exercise finally with the traditional method, using limit, and had to thread a way much longer path.